# android - Is possible delete a file from external/internal storage from PHP?

Tags: php, android

I need to remove a file from internal/external storage in smartphone that have my app installed, using PHP. I can't update my app if I don't remove this file.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to build the logic within the app my friend which has got nothing to do with PHP

Comment: "that have my app installed, using PHP"---> whaaaat ô_Ô ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly you can't do that but there should be workaround using some other methods like:

- Push Notifications
- Schedulers that checks URL endpoint with command logic

as web and PHP don't have any kind of accessing mobile device directly